# Using variables in loop bash

Tags: bash, loops, variables, eval

I have four variables like:

```
a1="11"
a2="22"
b1="111"
b2="222"
```

and now I want to create a loop to check if it is null or not:

```
for (( i=1; i<=2; i++)); do
    eval "a=a$i"
    eval "b=b$i"
    if [ -z $a ] || [ -z $b ]; then
        echo "variable-$a: condition is true"
    fi
done
```

I want to count `variable a and b` then print the content of that. But in this way doesn't work and it checks:

```
a1
a2
b1
b2
```

But I need to check:

```
11
22
111
222
```

Comment: There is the number zero (`0`), there are empty variables (`""`), there are unset variables. But what is `null` supposed to be?

Comment: Thank you, please check the update

Comment: Could these be passed as one variable of the form `"11 22 111 222"` instead?

Comment: No these are seperated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use variable indirection expansion:

```
for (( i=1; i<=2; i++)); do
    a=a$i
    b=b$i
    if [ -z "${!a}" ] || [ -z "${!b}" ]; then
        echo "variable-$a: condition is true"
    fi
done
```

> But in this way doesn't work and it checks:

Because you never expanded the variables, there is no point in `eval` in your code. Your code is just:

```
for (( i=1; i<=2; i++)); do
    a="a$i"
    b="b$i"
    # Remember to quote variable expansions!
    if [ -z "$a" ] || [ -z "$b" ]; then
        echo "variable-$a: condition is true"
    fi
done
```

while you could:

```
for (( i=1; i<=2; i++)); do
    eval "a=\"\$a$i\""
    eval "b=\"\$b$i\""
    if [ -z "$a" ] || [ -z "$b" ]; then
        echo "variable-a$i: condition is true"
    fi
done
```

but there is no need for evil eval.